# Running PEX line through PVC then thread into end

Tags: plumbing, hose, irrigation, gardening, lawn

I installed an irrigation system for my lawn with 1/2" PEX tubing. Most of it is buried, but at the start of the run I want to run it through some PVC to make it look cleaner where it is coming up from the ground, where my water timer is.

My issue is I want it to look really clean, so I want the top of the PVC run coming up from the ground to have a female garden hose thread on it, where I can then attach my water timer. I am trying to figure out how I can connect my PEX line that is running through the PVC to a fitting that attaches to the top of the PVC with a female garden hose end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to run your pex cable up the PVC pipe and put a PEX/ female hose connector on the end of the pex. (see below)

[image]

Another alternative would be to connect the pex to your PVC pipe at the bottom with this type of connector

[image]

and then at the top of the PVC pipe connect a female hose fitting

[image]

Your PC pipe would actually be under pressure at this point.
These fittings are available at home stores and plumbing supply stores.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to avoid using the PVC as a line because I wanted to use a much bigger diameter and use it as more of a conduit for the PEX line

Comment: @Chad  then something like the first  picture, your large PVC with a cap on it, drill a hole in the cap and fit your female hose end to pex into the cap.

Comment: You could also get a hose and cut off the female end with a foot or two of hose. Fit the female end into the hole in the cap and then connect your pex to the hose.